# How to delete a file except in any one of the subdirectory using shell script

Tags: shell

Hi I want to delete a file from any of the subdirectories except one of the subdirectory.

For ex

```
folder a->a.txt
folder b->subdir 1 -> msgdir-> a.txt
folder c->
```

Now i want to delete a.txt  only in folder a but not the file in msgdir .msgdir can be in any level of subdirectories as it would be changing.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear. Do you also want to delete other files or you care about `a.txt` only?

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore specifically the `msgdir` at any level and remove `a.txt` except in msgdir.

`find . ! -path '*/msgdir/*' -name a.txt -type f -delete`

Tested with GNU find 4.4.2 and BSD find (Mac Yosemite).

Comment: I was trying something like that but couldn't get it to work...much better than my idea!

Comment: I guess you should add `-name a.txt` too.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is overkill if you have GNU find (or a newer BSD one), with the `-path` option. Otherwise, read on...

You haven't specified which shell you're using but if you have bash, you could go with something like this:

```
find -name a.txt -exec bash -c "[[ '{}' != */msgdir/* ]]" \; -print
```

This filters out paths containing `/msgdir/`, as the test will only pass if the file path doesn't contain the string. If you're happy with the results, you can change `-print` to `-delete`.

Without bash, you could use grep to determine the match:

```
find -name a.txt -exec sh -c "printf '%s' '{}' | grep -qv '/msgdir/'" \; -print
```